# WordPress Multisite Add User

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles

Have allowed users to register their own website and at the same time this adds them as a user to that site.

However, is there a way to default them to a subscriber of the site they are signing up for rather than automatically adding them as a administrator.

I've looked around in the mess that is wp-signup.php and wp-activate.php and it doesn't look to specify them as an admin anywhere.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What would be the point of that? Why would anyone start a site if he can do nothing in it?

Comment: There are plenty of use-cases. But thanks for questioning my question.

Comment: so many, you can't even list one..... doing something contrary to how core is designed to work is rarely a good thing. If you spell out your use case someone might offer you an alternative

Comment: It's a SaaS app. Different levels of service. The basic level only allows them to set-up a read-only website. Not that this will help the opening question. But for your curiosity.

Comment: and how do they change the site, via user profile?

Comment: Because with different levels of service they will be allowed multiple pages, posts and a full website. Trust me, I've done it the right way. Back to the question as this is irrelevant.

Upon sign-up I will check a meta field that you use at the payment gateway and I will set the users role depending on their service plan.

So the opening question asks can I default this to subscriber.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51088/discussion-between-chewx-and-mark-kaplun).

Comment: There are hooks after user and site creation. You can set the user role per the site that was created back to subscriber. Not sure there is any better way, but the user email will still be set as the admin email, not sure how this will interact with other things.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this isn't possible to do by default.

As I already had a hook for `wpmu_activate_blog()` I just created another with a lower priority which will be fired after. This function also has the 2 parameters I need. So upon activation of the account I simply remove Admin role and set a new role based of the subscription service level.

```php
add_action( 'wpmu_activate_blog', array( $this,'set_new_user_role' ), 15, 2 );

public function set_new_user_role( $blog_id, $user_id ) {
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id, '', $blog_id );

    $user->remove_role( 'administrator' );

    // @NOTE - Set this role depending on user subscription level.
    $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like the [multisite role management plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-role-manager/). It allows you to define the user roles to have by default on a per blog basis, in a multisite setting

Comment: And assuming I have the plugin, how do I use it to achieve what the question asks for?

Comment: Thanks @codiiv , unfortunately it still requires manual role change. I guess I'll just write some PHP that converts back to subscriber. Currently having difficulty finding the hook that I would need. wp-activate.php doesn't have any after activation, only before.

Comment: wpmu_create_blog  can be used  to hook a function that updates  the user's role

Comment: That is only called for existing users. This is pre-user set-up. The process would be completed all at once, site and user.

Comment: If I am correct, the right logic would be : 1) Sign up for blog (Wp registers the blog and adds admin access) 2) Demote  from admin to subscriber. I don't think I pre-user setup wouldn't  work

Comment: Correct. but the function you supplied is only called when a logged in user signs up for a site. Not someone not signed in.

Going to use https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wpmu_new_blog as per Mark Kaplun's suggestion.